# What is common parlance for the product of applying a single production rule?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction

I'm wondering if there is a conventional name for the result of applying a single production rule in the course of parsing?

So say my grammar has this production:

```
attr -> NAME, EQUAL, TEXT
```

Then in the course of parsing I match that production and have a small collection of data that represents the substitution/match:

```
((NAME, 'foo'), (EQUAL, '='), (TEXT, 'bar'))
```

What would convention dictate that be called? The candidates I've collected so far are:

- *production* -- I don't like this option because despite these items being what was "produced" by application of the rule, the 'attr -> NAME, EQUAL, TEXT' bit already lays legitimate claim to that term.
- *partial derivation* -- I'd prefer a single word, but this makes sense to me as the entire parse result is a derivation and this is one "atom" or step of that derivation.
- *replacement* -- I kind of like this one okay, but it seems a little generic.

Aside from an obsessive desire to fully articulate the solution domain, a function (perhaps `match(rule, tokens)`) that takes a production rule and returns the matching tokens (and/or resolved non-terminals) needs a name for what it returns (or at least its caller does).

The next step, in my case anyway, is to use these values to produce a node in the abstract syntax tree (AST), but that node is a separate object with potentially different form and additional fields.

Does someone with wider experience in parsing and compiler terminology know of a term that would be appropriate for this?

Comment: Are you perhaps thinking of something along the lines of the "reduce" step of [shift-reduce parsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift-reduce_parser)?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: that was my reaction, too.  See my answer.

Comment: Actually, no, I don't think I've gotten that far in my parsing repetoire yet :) The parsing strategy I'm using is top-down, recursive descent. So for each nonterminal in the body of a candidate production I attempt a (recursive) match against each production rule for that nonterminal, in the order defined. The first one to match returns the result whose name cannot (yet) be mentioned :)  I'm very keen on the shift-reduce strategy though, that will be next up on my learning journey once I've gotten this one sussed out. Apologies, I see now I ought to have mentioned :)

Comment: @scanny: my point was that the vocabulary from shift-reduce parsers apply ... because after you see the production, you reduce the right hand side logically to its nonterminal.   Abstractly your top parser does something similar: it proposes ("calls") to parse a nonterminal (the LHS), parses the elemenst of the rules, and then is finished with the nonterminal ("returns").  That last step acts like a reduction: it is done with all the rule tokens.

Comment: Ah, now I get it, thanks for bearing with my being dense on that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bottom up parsing (e.g, LALR), the recognition of parts of one or more production rules is done efficiently by building a complex FSA in which states essentially encode what productions might match what has been seen up to a certain point in the input.  The vocabulary:

- the act of processing a token and making unit progress in matching part of (more than one) production, is called a *shift* (it is a transition in the FSA, plus recording in a parse stack that the transition has taken place)
- after arriving (by shifting one or more times) at the apparent end of some production, the parser will execute one (or more) *reductions*, each of which signals the recognition of a production.  Each reduction for a specific production rule R of length L, pops L entries from the parse stack, to determine the state of the FSA after the reduction. The parser then attempts to shift on a token for the left hand side of the production.

You appear to be interested in naming the status of being ready to do a reduction.  There isn't a term I've seen used to name this status, but I would nominate **reducible** as being a reasonable term.

(What actually happens in an LALR parser in a reducible state, is that the next [as yet unshifted] input token, the *lookahead*, is checked against a [state-specific] lookahead set for the production, to see if one can really use the production in a reduction. [In effect, this is checking that the production is valid in the context in which it is found.] If one can, then a reduction takes place; if not, then the production does not actually apply and is ignored; there better be a valid shift on the lookahead token in this case).

Comment: Ok, after a nights sleep on this, I'm thinking the term "expansion" is actually the best fit. It's like "reducible", except I'm going the other direction, and basically giving the command "expand this nonterminal into the (recursive) sequence of symbols in the token stream that first match one of its productions". What do you think of that? Not sure I'd choose it for a textbook term, but I'm thinking it meets the standard for a variable name and is actually pretty good intuitively, like take this one thing and expand it into multiple things :)

Comment: Yes, you could use "expansion of the LHS nonterminal" as a phrase that wouldn't confuse anybody.  After all, you're trying to expand the goal nonterminal into the sequence of tokens that match the program. The technical term "derivation" is normally used for this, e.g, "LHS derives (RHS terms)".  "Reducible" views from the other side:  if I have a sequence of tokens, they can be reduced to a nonterminal.  They are opposite but symmetric.   In any case, pick a good term, write down its definition, and *use it consistently* if you are going to use it all.